# C# lambda expression to filter by minutes

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda

I am trying to get log entries using c# and lambda expression for last 1 day. 
Any pointer on how to get data for specific duration like 15 mins or 15 hours etc., Tried .AddMinutes but it did not work. Any example please.

```
_context.LogEntities
.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.timestamp) > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
```

I tried this which did not work

```
_context.LogEntities
.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.timestamp) > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2))
```

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate in 15 minute buckets, or something else?

Comment: As far as your question is concerned this looks like it should work, please add more detail

Comment: @TheGeneral Not for EF which is what I'm guessing it is because of `_context`.

Comment: What is the DB type for `timestamp`.  If it's not a date/time type then I highly recommend redesigning your DB if possible.  Then create the date you want to compare it to in a variable and use that in the query.  Otherwise I'm not sure EF supports converting strings to datetime types, so you might have to use native SQL instead.

Comment: For example I tried this which did not work

    _context.LogEntities
    .Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.timestamp) > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2))

Comment: I think you should specify -2 as AddHours argument!

Comment: you are making comparisons using local time, not sure what time is in your data... if you have UTC it might be a problem

Comment: this really seems to be unlikely; but still asking, have you confirmed that in `_context.LogEntities` there are appropriate entries. As you current lamada doesn't seem to wrong.

Comment: I am mistaken in this case, I am in PST and comparing UTC. Thanks for every ones time.

Comment: I would avoid using `Convert` whenever possible.  What type/format is `p.timestamp` in?  I would suggest using methods on `DateTime` to construct a `DateTime` with more control.